# Loop over different subdirectories

Tags: r, loops, subdirectory

I'm new to R and so not very familiar to even simple functions yet. 
Short description of my attempt: I got one direktory with several subdirectories (11 subdirectories, as seen in the code below ). Each of this subdir. has got the same struckture. Each of this subdir. contains four .csv-files, called gwn,rh,ro and rg1. I want to read each of the gwn.csv one by one and write parts of it to another file, that has been created in my main morking folder.

Thats my last try:

```
files<-list.files("../Tagessummen")
```

That gives me the structure of the direktory that looks like:

```
[1] "Beobachtet"    "Projektion_00" "Projektion_11"
[4] "Projektion_22" "Projektion_33" "Projektion_44"
[7] "Projektion_55" "Projektion_66" "Projektion_77"
[10] "Projektion_88" "Projektion_99"
```

Now i thougt i could use this for defining the loop-path.
I tried with this:

```
for(i in 1:length(files))
  Grundwasserneubildung_Daten<-read.table('../Tagessummen/',files,'/zeit.dat/Tag/geb_sum.gwn')
  Grundwasserneubildung_Daten<-Grundwasserneubildung_Daten[-1,-1]
  Grundwasserneubildung<-cbind(Grundwasserneubildung,Grundwasserneubildung_Daten)
end
```

But it does not work. I think, it has something to do with the definition of the loop.
I did read lots of similar questions, but nothig worked so far.

2nd questions wolud be, how to implement another loop, to read and work with the other three files in the same'one-by-one'-manner. Hope you got some enlightening answer for me.

Comment: "length" not spelled correctly?

Comment: Thx, but unfortunately not the missing link .-)

Comment: `read.table(paste('../Tagessummen/',files,'/zeit.dat/Tag/geb_sum.gwn'))`?  Or with `file.path` for better compatibility, if needed?

Comment: Also would help if you showed what the error is.  We're just guessing here.

Comment: Well, `end` is not a for-loop term in R and you probably need to index the lines after `read.table` with `i` and wrap them all in curly braces.

Comment: Sorry, thats my first time on this Board. I'll try to explain my attempt again in short. I want to create a loop, that, one after another, reads a certain file called 'geb_sum.gwn'. This file is to be found in every of that 11 subdirectories mentioned above ('files')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
files<-list.files("../Tagessummen")

Grundwasserneubildung_Daten <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  Grundwasserneubildung_Daten[[i]]<-read.table(paste0('../Tagessummen/',files[i],'/zeit.dat/Tag/geb_sum.gwn'))[-1,-1]
}

Grundwasserneubildung <- do.call(cbind,Grundwasserneubildung_Daten)
```

This builds a list of dataframes then uses `do.call()` to call `cbind()` on all the dataframes at the end.  The `cbind()` won't work if the files are different lengths, though.

One error was the improper structure of the `for` loop.  The second is that you need `paste0()` to concatenate the string properly.  A third error is that `files` is a vector of file names, so when you concatenate the strings together, you are attempting to read in a vector of file names, which won't work as planned.  Using `files[i]` instead of just `files` references a single element (file name) of the vector at a time.